# How to select and remove specific elements or find their index in a vector or matrix?

Tags: r, vector, matrix, indices

Let's say I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,16,20,7,2)

y <- c(1, 7, 5,2,4,16,20,10)
```

I want to remove elements in `y` that are not in `x`. That is, I want to remove elements `5, 4, 10` from `y`.

```
y
[1] 1 7 2 16 20
```

In the end, I want vectors `x` and `y` to have to same elements. Order does not matter.

My thoughts: The `match` function lists the indices of the where the two vectors contains a matching element but I need a function is that essentially the opposite. I need a function that displays the indices where the elements in the two vectors don't match.

```
# this lists the indices in y that match the elements in x
match(x,y)
[1] 1 6 7 2 4   # these are the indices that I want; I want to remove
                # the other indices from y
```

Does anyone know how to do this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are after `intersect`

```
intersect(x,y)
## [1]  1 16 20  7  2
```

If you want the indices for the elements of `y` in `x`, using `which` and `%in%` (`%in%` uses `match` internally, so you were on the right track here)

```
which(y %in% x)
## [1] 1 2 4 6 7
```

As @joran points out in the comments `intersect` will drop the duplicates, so perhaps a safe option, if you want to return true matches would be something like

```
intersection <- function(x,y){.which <- intersect(x,y)
 .in <- x[which(x %in% y)]
 .in}


x <- c(1,1,2,3,4)
y <- c(1,2,3,3)

intersection(x,y)
## [1] 1 1 2 3
# compare with
intersect(x,y)
## [1] 1 2 3

intersection(y,x)
## [1] 1 2 3 3
# compare with 
intersect(y, x)
## [1] 1 2 3
```

You then need to be careful about ordering with this modified function (which is avoided with `intersect` as it drops duplicated elements )

---

If you want the index of those element of y not in x, simply prefix with `!` as `%in% returns a logical vector

```
which(!y%in%x)

##[1] 3 5 8
```

Or if you want the elements use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(y,x)
## [1]  5  4 10
```

Comment: Only curveball I can think of is that `intersect` will drop duplicated elements.

Comment: thanks I think that's function I need but how do I list the indices in `y` that don't contain elements in `x`?

Comment: @joran, good point, i've added a function that will return all elements, and also examples of setdiff and not in

Comment: thank you @mnel and joran. If I had more reputation points, I would give you both a thumbs up.